# How to change boost threads limitation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool

So I try to create simple speed bench with boost 1.47.0. But if I try to create more than 1450 threads it throws exeption. How to get rid of such boost::tread limitation?

My code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

class TestDs 
{
public:

    virtual bool containsKey(int key)=0;
    virtual int get(int key)=0;
    virtual int put(int key, int value)=0;
    virtual int remove(int key)=0;
    virtual int size()=0;
    virtual const char* name()=0;
    virtual void print()=0;
    virtual void shutdown()=0;
};

class GeneralMap: public TestDs
{
private:

    std::map<int,int> _ds;
    mutable boost::mutex mut_;
public:
    GeneralMap() {}

    bool containsKey(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        if ( _ds.find(key) != _ds.end())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int get(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds[key];
    }

    int put(int key, int value) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        _ds.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key,value));
        return key;
    }

    int remove(int key) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds.erase(key);
    }

    int size() {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mut_);
        return _ds.size();
    }
    const char* name() {
        return "StdMap";
    }
    void print() {}
    void shutdown() {}

};

int n;
boost::shared_mutex  tests;
boost::shared_mutex  results;
boost::timer timerForCaptureFame;
GeneralMap Ds;

void test( int i)
{
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
    Ds.put(i, 0);
    if (Ds.containsKey(i))
    {
        Ds.get(i);
    }
    Ds.remove(i);
}

void result()
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(results);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    std::cout <<  std::endl << "test of " << Ds.name() << " complite;" << std::endl << "test performed on " << n << " items" << std::endl << "test duration: " << timerForCaptureFame.elapsed() << std::endl;
}

void create_tests( int n)
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
    boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        boost::thread worker(test, i);
    }
    boost::thread worker_r(result);
    timerForCaptureFame.restart();
    return;
}

int main()
{
    n = 1000;// if n == 1600 crushes.
    create_tests(n);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you creating so many threads?

Comment: I agree with Maz, threads gradually get less useful after you have more threads than processing cores. A sane application should never have even close to 1450 threads, much less even 100.

Comment: to make a bench - how fast can we write/read/eraise from map in a concurrent fashon. (imagine we have a server and each request shall be served on server side by one new thread. Each thread shall write into log map that it was created, than it shall eraise itself from that map. If we have 1600 requesters our serer will crush)

Comment: @Kabumbus use non-blocking I/O instead of a thread per connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not so sure it is a limitation of Boost, but a limitation of Windows. According to [Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx) the maximum threads on a 32 bit OS is 2048 which means you have allocated approximatly 3/4's of the maximum allowed threads. If you have other processes running it will decrease the amount of threads available for you to use.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Is your application a 64-bit application?